# Scaling Large CSS Background Images For Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, responsive-design

I'm currently building a XenForo theme that's designed to showcase a full-screen, moderately high-resolution photo background using transparency and fun CSS3 effects. However, I'm fearing a rather nasty scaling problem - especially on small devices. As you might imagine, it pains me to think of a visitor trying to load a photo that's nearly a megabyte on a 3G or GPRS connection.

The background in question is a fixed background-image attached to the `<html>` element.

What would be a suitable way of dealing with the scale problem? There's only so much compression I would do, so would a JavaScript-based solution to serve a suitably sized image for the viewport/device be effective enough? Are there any other solutions that I could consider?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Do you need this bg image on mobile?

Comment: Is something wrong with using media queries to serve an appropriately scaled background image to smaller devices?

Comment: @cimmanon: I'd honestly not thought of it. However, it's a very good idea and one I will probably do.

Comment: @ScottSimpson: Ideally, yes.

Comment: Here is a good blog article on the subject: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: The results of the tests in the article that Scott Simpson posted show that the exact method used matters and some of the behavior is non-obvious. If you do it wrong mobile browsers will download both images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deliver a lower resolution image to mobile browsers. One way to do this is to use CSS media queries: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above using the CSS functionality `@media` you can serve the right image size for all device types. Have a look at Twitter's CSS framework [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

I would recommend using a small image for all requests but replace it only for desktop browser but tablets could use both, a slow internet connection as well as fast wifi access. This requires a more complex solution.

In addition using AJAX for serving the images would likely speed up the page a lot.